# Java get a current time in 24h format

Tags: java, time, calendar

Now i getting a current time

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

and `hours` is always retrieving in 12h format. How i can change my code to getting actual hours in 24h format?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the Javadoc.  I downvoted you because you think it's better to waste the time of hundreds of people who will see this question, than to spend a few seconds looking this up.

Comment: @DavidWallace Where does Javadoc? Yes, it's simple question, but you will can spend less of your time to write an answer instead of downwoting and explantation why.

Comment: If only there were some kind of tool that could be used for finding pages on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) that is used for the 24-hour clock.

```
int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working. I can't accept it for now. Stack allow accepting it to me at 12 minutes.